# Putting Facebook profile picture to UIImage

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, uiimage, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get a profile picture from Graph API by calling `me/picture` or `<friend_id>/picture`. However it seems that the response that's given is not a JSON response. I haven't been able to read the response, but I know it's suppose to be another URL that links to the profile picture JPEG file.

I know that once I get that URL I can use `UIImage` method `imageFromURL` (or something like that) but I'm just not sure how to process the response. Can someone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make request like

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andDelegate:self];
```

and your response handler

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    {
        UIImage* profilePicture = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: result];
    }
 }
```

Comment: This form has been deprecated. The new format is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20623845

Answer (score 0):

Mayb this would help you:
[How To Get a User Profile with Facebook’s New Graph API from your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)

Comment: I read that blog post before, but he's just getting a first name and last name from Graph API, not profile picture =(

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URL and not the image data, then see my answer here: [iOS Facebook Graph API Profile picture link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444931/ios-facebook-graph-api-profile-picture-link/10493637#10493637)