# Graph API iOS picture

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I have a graph api call from my ios application.  It looks something like this:

```
[[appDelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i/picture", [[userData objectForKey:@"id"] intValue] andDelegate:self];
```

(might be some typos)

But in the request did load when i nslog the result, it is `(null)`.  Graph API says that you need to use fields=picture or something to get the url.  How would I do this?  If it is possible could somebody show me some example code?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an actual Graph API call to load a user's facebook picture.  Simply construct a url like this, and it will return the specified user's facebook image:

```
NSURL *fbPictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", [userData objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

You can then do with that what you want, like load it in an UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on this post to see how to get the picture URL using requestWithGraphPath:

[iOS Facebook Graph API Profile picture link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444931/ios-facebook-graph-api-profile-picture-link/10493637#10493637)