# Firebase Facebook Authentication missing photo field in 'thirdPartyUserData'

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I am using Firebase simple login with Facebook, and have encountered a little problem last night.  After logging in with permissions as an empty array (default) I get this

```
thirdPartyUserData = {
    email = <String>
    "first_name" = <String>
    gender = <String>
    id = <String>
    "last_name" = <String>
    link = <String>
    name = <String>
}
```

The difference is that now adays I do not see the 'picture' field, which was a dictionary with 'data' (and within 'data', 'url')...  This change happened last night, is anyone else having the same problem with their authentication?

The permissions I have been logging on with are just [], (providing no permissions just uses the default)

Comment: Are you still observing this? I just attempted to reproduce this issue, but I am getting the user's profile photo in thirdPartyUserData.picture.data.url

Comment: This is still occuring.  However, when I tried to do the same thing using Firebase's js sdk, I have no problem.  i have solved my problem by reconstructing the facebook profile image url from the facebook user's id.

Comment: Ah got it  iOS. I tried to repro with JS. It looks like Facebook treats them a bit differently.  Does this other answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20623845/839465

Comment: Thanks Jenny Tong!  I think what I'll just do is rely on the knowledge of `@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=small` points to their icon (or if they do not have an icon it has a default no-icon image.  (Although, one day before this post, I was able to see 'picture' field in thirdPartyUserData, but no longer, yet firebase js auth still shows this field.  Weird.)

Comment: Got it. I'll investigate and update this question once I learn more :)

Comment: Thanks! You guys are Firebase are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your time,

I haven't exactly solved the issue but incase anybody else is having the same problem (on iOS) as I am, you should check out the approach suggested by Jenny Tong;  incase of the absence of profile icon, you can reconstruct the url;

`http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=small
http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal
http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large`

where %@ is facebookID of the user.  So in my case, I do the normal ...

`authClient.loginToFacebookAppWithId(kFacebookAppId, permissions: [], audience: ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe, withCompletionBlock:
        {(error:NSError!, user:FAUser!) in ...})`

and if I do not find `picture` in `thirdPartyUserData`, i fall back on the above reconstruction.  It works even if the user has not facebook profile image (you get default silhouette).

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the third party data are the purview of Facebook and part of their API; it can change at any time they choose. The specific options you can enable and what you receive back are covered [in this Facebook page under "reference"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference). You may want to experiment with those. I do see "user_photos" under the extended permissions.

Regarding your "permissions array": To control what appears in the contents of `thirdPartyUserData`, you set those parameters as part of a **comma delimited `scope` variable** in simple login (a string not an array). Read the [Facebook guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/simple-login/facebook.html) for a little info on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I have found that this is a problem possibly only on the Firebase iOS sdk; I tried from the web component and did not have any troubles.  Also, user_photos is a little too much permission, I only want their profile icon & Firebase requires that you pass an array of permissions.