# How to get profile picture from FBLoginView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

Please help me to get Facebook Profile Picture using FBLoginView.

Not setting FBProfileImageView. I want to get the UIImage of Profile Picture.

NOTE : Not using Custom Facebook Login. I am using FBLoginView for login.

Comment: did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623728/getting-username-and-profile-picture-from-facebook-ios-7)

Comment: Hey sorry. It was using custom facebook login. I am using FBLoginView for  login. So, my case is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After login View we get users ID,email,gender and many more things so we can use user ID or objectID to get the user Profile Image.

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{        
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal",user.id]];
    NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

profileImage would contain the user profile Image and you can use that.

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me how to manage login with FBLoginView ? I have a signin/signup page which doesn't need to show if the user already logged in with FBLoginView. How to manage it ?

Comment: how to check whether the user logged in or not using FBLoginView ?

Comment: u can use -(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView to see if user id logged out.