# Get Profile Photo from Facebook in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented Facebook login in my app & get the details of the user.

I try to get user Profile Picture as per following:

```
 FBimage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[result valueForKeyPath:@"picture.data.url"]]]];
```

But this takes almost 3 minutes to get picture & code below this this line will also halt execution.

**Help me to solve this**

**Thanks**

Comment: use sdwebimage third party tool...https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Refer to the answer below and use @Guilherme's answer's query with parameters specifying either type small or explicit height and width. That will lower the size of image and make download faster. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623728/getting-username-and-profile-picture-from-facebook-ios-7

Answer (score 1):

You can set `AsyncImageView` instead of `UIImageview` so Image will load Asyncronouslly

Answer (score 0):

I have also this type of problem with image.

Use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

```
[imgViewContactImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"imagename"]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"] completed:nil];
```

import "UIImageView+WebCache.h" first

Please try this.

share your feedback.

Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"picture", @"user_friends"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error

            NSLog(@"efv");
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
            NSLog(@"efv");



        } else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                // Do work
                [self fetchUserDetail];


            }
        }

        [login logOut];

    }];

-(void)fetchUserDetail
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name,email,gender,picture"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {


                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);



             }
             else
             {

             }
         }];
    }
}
```